# Using @Named with Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I used to use the standard annotations @Named and @Inject for dependency injection in my code, and the Spring annotation @Primary to force the usage of a specific implementation in case I have multi implementations.
Unfortunately, this is not working with Quarkus anymore. Is there any specific reason ?
Is there any solution that  can work for both Quarkus and a Web Application (The library that I am implementing can be used in both type of applications)?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you seeing?

Comment: The class annotated with @Named is never injected.